# Ошибка с показом букв в listview

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, adapter

В `ListView` текст вместо букв отображается ромбиками со знаками вопросов. В чем причина?

Небольшой апдейт: цифры отображаются нормально... А вот буквы нет. Поэтому захардкоренность отпадает

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package ru.N.wo;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayList<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Заполняем данными

        list.add(new Contact("1111", "47ап", "ттт", "Яггг, Пее", "еее"));
        list.add(new Contact("2222", "67п", "еееку", "мттм", "аиаа"));
        list.add(new Contact("3333", "98вп", "ттт", "уим, иеу", "Еаа"));
        list.add(new Contact("4444", "13дв", "yyy", "иаы, аиа", "вв"));
        list.add(new Contact("5555", "77ьв", "панк", "пвп, куя", "мммм"));
        list.add(new Contact("6666", "34pпвп", "куй", "пвп, Пвпв", "пп"));
        list.add(new Contact("77", "42pп", "народ", "Алгебра, математика", "ппп"));
        list.add(new Contact("879", "13пв", "ФИзика", "лла, право", "френч"));
        list.add(new Contact("3535", "24ав", "Химия", "нана", "Ее"));


        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.group_view,
                new String[] {Contact.TI, Contact.CO, Contact.NA, Contact.S, Contact.HO}, new int[] {
                R.id.te, R.id.to, R.id.tr, R.id.st, R.id.ho });
        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }

}
```

**group_view.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/eor"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        >
    <ImageView android:layout_width="50dp"
               android:layout_height="50dp"
               android:background="@drawable/koko"
               android:id="@+id/imageView25"

               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="50dp"
               android:layout_height="50dp"
               android:background="@drawable/rruururu"
               android:id="@+id/imageView5"

               android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/to"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
    <View
            android:id="@+id/separator1"
            android:layout_width="5px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/separator1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lo" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stations"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ho"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/ttt"

            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/te"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tr" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView200"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/line"
               android:id="@+id/lo"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/drawer_item_color"

            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tr"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/text1"

        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/ho"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/te"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tr"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/about"

        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/st"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ho" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ho"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/about"

        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/to"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tr" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Contact.class**

```
 package ru.N.wo;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Contact extends HashMap<String, String> {
    public static final String TI = "ti";
    public static final String CO = "co";
    public static final String NA = "na";
    public static final String ST = "st";
    public static final String HO = "ho";

    // Конструктор с параметрами
    public Contact(String ti, String co, String na, String st, String ho) {
        super();
        super.put(TI, ti);
        super.put(CO, co);
        super.put(NA, na);
        super.put(ST, st);
        super.put(HO, ho);






    }
}
```

Comment: Смотрите кодировку в проекте - она должна быть UTF. Хотите  больше полей с текстом  в списке - пишите свой адаптер и выводите там что хотите

Comment: Этот ресурс не для личных консультаций, когда создаете вопрос, подумайте о том, что в будущем он должен помочь решить проблему  кому-то еще. В частности, не надо спрашивать две разных проблемы в одном вопросе. Один вопрос - одна проблема - однозначное решение.

Comment: @pavlofff, извините, а где вы видите 2 вопроса?

Comment: Про [вывод пяти строк](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/423039/revisions) я что ли спрашивал ? Создавайте новый вопрос по другой проблеме

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том что вы захардкодили строковые значения, а они все должны быть вынесены в `strings.xml` и аналогичные.

UPD. Поясню:

Конкретно проблема в этом фрагменте кода: `"1111", "47ап", "ттт", "Яггг, Пее", "еее"` и аналогичных. Если вы обратите внимание то в xml файлах, втч. strings.xml первой строкой идет `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` т.е. явно указывается кодировка в которой этот файл.

У `.java` файлов с кодом нет такой особенности поэтому все символы кроме первых 128 из таблицы ASCII будут отображаться некорректно - их нужно выносить в `strings.xml`

Ниже табличка из википедии с первыми 128 символами. В частности там присутствуют цифры и английский алфавит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как их из массива выносить, скажите пожалуйста

Comment: обновил вопрос. Посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @DenShDen вы ответ читали?