# Как выносить строки программно в strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

После парсинга приходит 5 массивов. Нужно: взять значения каждого, и создавать новые массивы по типу (первое слово первого массива-первое слово второго-третьего-четвертого-пятого) и так далее.. Потом эти новые массивы вынести в `strings.xml`, и затем программно оттуда их вывести в `listview` через `SimpleAdapter`. Как это сделать?)

Comment: Воу воу воу...зачем заносить в strings.xml? Нельзя к адаптеру просто подключить эти массивы? Что вообще должно быть в listView, пример можно?

Comment: @Rishka ,да я уже вопрос просто задавал, сейчас кину... Ответили, что я захардкорил, поэтому нормально все не пропечатывается.. вот, почитайте http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423039/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2-%D0%B2-listview

Comment: в том вопросе строки забиты программно. А сейчас вы говорите, что они как-то парсятся. Не путайтесь:) Если у вас есть готовый набор строк, который статичен и не меняется - его вы заносите в strings.xml. Если динамически откуда-то стягивается или вы его как-то формируете, то не нужно этого делать:)

Comment: @Rishka, динамически, но ведь проблема то разве исчезает?)

Comment: как вы его получаете? Значит сервер вам в неверной кодировке отдает эти строки. Плюс, поменяйте кодировку справа внизу. Поставьте UTF-8

Comment: @Rishka, с помощью jsoup парсю данные с сайта, приходит..) а всмысле справа внизу кодировка?где?

Comment: "справа-внизу" - это значит справа-внизу :)) [картинка](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8fQlR.png)

Comment: Либо можете через настройки. Settings ->Project Settings -> File encoding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш вопрос некорректен.
Проблема в том, как вы получаете эти строки, а не как вы их выводите, вам советуют перенести строки в string.xml, потому что он UTF-8, так же советуют переключить кодировку файла, в правом нижнем углу IDE(справедливо для intellij IDEA и Android Studio вероятно). Если вы получаете эти строки с помощью jsoup, то эти советы неприменимы и ответ на прошлый вопрос неверен! Погуглил вот пример который **вероятно** может вам помочь:

```
String url = "http://www.latijnengrieks.com/vertaling.php?id=5368";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8", url);
Element paragraph = document.select("div.kader p").first();

for (Node node : paragraph.childNodes()) {
    if (node instanceof TextNode) {
        System.out.println(((TextNode) node).text().trim());
    }
}
```

Суть в стоке "UTF-8"